# Matching a value with a list

Tags: python

I have two variables like below. The goal is to check if the value in baseAU variable matches "out" or not. What is the easiest way this can be done? One way is to split-up out and put in a list and parse over it. Are there any other simple ways?

```
baseAU = "AU_LINUX_ANDROID_test.04.02.01.40.144"

out=
"
AU_LINUX_ANDROID_test.04.02.01.40.134
AU_LINUX_ANDROID_test.04.02.01.40.135
AU_LINUX_ANDROID_test.04.02.01.40.136
AU_LINUX_ANDROID_test.04.02.01.40.137
AU_LINUX_ANDROID_test.04.02.01.40.138
AU_LINUX_ANDROID_test.04.02.01.40.139
AU_LINUX_ANDROID_test.04.02.01.40.140
AU_LINUX_ANDROID_test.04.02.01.40.141
AU_LINUX_ANDROID_test.04.02.01.40.142
AU_LINUX_ANDROID_test.04.02.01.40.143
AU_LINUX_ANDROID_test.04.02.01.40.144
AU_LINUX_ANDROID_test.04.02.01.40.145
AU_LINUX_ANDROID_dev.04.02.01.49.106
AU_LINUX_ANDROID_dev.04.02.01.49.107
AU_LINUX_ANDROID_dev.04.02.01.49.108
AU_LINUX_ANDROID_dev.04.02.01.49.109
AU_LINUX_ANDROID_dev.04.02.01.49.110
AU_LINUX_ANDROID_dev.04.02.01.49.111
AU_LINUX_ANDROID_dev.04.02.01.49.112
AU_LINUX_ANDROID_dev.04.02.01.49.113
AU_LINUX_ANDROID_dev.04.02.01.49.114
AU_LINUX_ANDROID_dev.04.02.01.49.115
AU_LINUX_ANDROID_dev.04.02.01.49.116
AU_LINUX_ANDROID_dev.04.02.01.49.117
AU_LINUX_ANDROID_dev.04.02.01.49.118
"
```

Comment: Have you tried `baseAU in out`?

Comment: yes,but is matching AU_LINUX_ANDROID_test.04.02.01.40.14 too(notice its actually AU_LINUX_ANDROID_test.04.02.01.40.144)

Answer (score 1):

Split your string up into a list:

```
baseAU in out.split()
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is just match the string, using `in`

```
if baseAU in out:
   print "Have match"
```

A more convenient way is to break the `out` variable into sets, and using the set `in` operator. This should be more efficient.

```
s = set(out.split())
if baseAU in s:
    print "Have match"
```

Comment: Wouldn't it only be more efficient if you need to check for multiple values in out? Seems to me that the overhead creating the set (and splitting by line if that's not required) would be overall more expensive if you're only checking for a single value one time.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to match the string with a line:

```
if "%s\n" % baseAU in out:
    print "Match"
```

AU_LINUX_ANDROID_test.04.02.01.40.14 will not match with AU_LINUX_ANDROID_test.04.02.01.40.144

Comment: Breaks if the newline starts with `\r`, which is the case in Windows and older Mac OSes.